# Terraform - Create a map of objects

Tags: terraform

This is doing my head in a little bit. So I want to create a map of objects like so:

```
{
  "nic_1" = {
    "interface_id" = "blah"
    "ip_configuration_name" = "blah"
  },
  "nic_2" = {
    "interface_id" = "blah"
    "ip_configuration_name" = "blah"
  },
}
```

The source for this data comes from the below list:

```
ni-resource = [
  {
    "id" = "blah"
    "ip_configuration" = [
      {
        "name" = "blah"
      },
    ]
    "name" = "nic_1"
  },
  {
    "id" = "blah"
    "ip_configuration" = [
      {
        "name" = "blah"
      },
    ]
    "name" = "nic_2"
  },
]
```

So in other words the `ni-resource->id` needs to map to `interface_id` and `ni-resource->ip_configuration->name` needs to map to `ip_configuration_name`.

I am trying to create a local as below which is not working:

```
locals {
  ni_list = { for ni in ni-resource : 
    ni["name"] => {
      interface_id = ni["id"]
      ip_configuration = ni["ip_configuration"][0]["name"]
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Error: Invalid object key

The key expression produced an invalid result: string required.
```

Here is the full ni-resource output:

```
ni-resource = [
  {
    "applied_dns_servers" = []
    "dns_servers" = []
    "enable_accelerated_networking" = false
    "enable_ip_forwarding" = false
    "id" = "blah"
    "internal_dns_name_label" = ""
    "internal_domain_name_suffix" = "blah"
    "ip_configuration" = [
      {
        "name" = "blah"
        "primary" = true
        "private_ip_address" = "dummy"
        "private_ip_address_allocation" = "Dynamic"
        "private_ip_address_version" = "IPv4"
        "public_ip_address_id" = ""
        "subnet_id" = "dummy"
      },
    ]
    "location" = "dummy"
    "mac_address" = ""
    "name" = "nic_1l"
    "private_ip_address" = "dummy"
    "private_ip_addresses" = [
      "dummy",
    ]
    "resource_group_name" = "dummy"
    "virtual_machine_id" = ""
  },
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify the issue? Why "its not working?" Any error messages?

Comment: @Marcin I have added the error message to the question.

Comment: I run your example, it works for me. No errors and the output is what you desire. But I used `ni-resource` as a variable `var.ni-resource` in my test. What is `ni-resource` in your case?

Comment: ni-resource is an output from another module. I get the above when I checked the output of the module.

Comment: Are you sure that that example you provided of `ni-resource` correctly represents your actual data? By the way I use terraform 0.13, and I have no issues with this code.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the ni-resource structure to the question. I have configured the version to be 0.13.

Comment: Ok figured where I was going wrong, I had another local configured somewhere else which I had not updated. Too much TF can be a bad thing as well. @Marcin appreciate your help.

Comment: Was about to make new comment, that the new structure also works :-)